# How to Get all Product Images From pub/media/catalog/product

Tags: magento2, file-permissions

I want to Get All Product Images From Catalog/Product Images Directory

I am trying this but not getting Success

```
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Index
{
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        File $io
    ) {
        $this->storeManager       = $storeManager;
        $this->_io                = $io;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $dir = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
            \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
        ) . 'catalog/product';
        $this->_io->chmodRecursive($dir, 0777);
        $images = $this->_io->ls($dir);
        echo $dir;
        print_r($images);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want images for specific product?

Comment: no i want all images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well After Some i Did it my Myself

```
class Index
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    ) {
           $this->dir                = $dir;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $dir = $this->dir->getPath('media') . '/catalog/product';
        $images      = $this->scd($dir);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($images);
        exit();
    }
}
public function scd($path)
    {
        $di       = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
        $files    = [];
        $allowed  = ['jpg'];
        foreach ($iterator as $file) {
            $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
                //if you want File Name With Path You can Try this
                $files[] = $file->getPathName();
                //if you want File Name Only You can Try this
                $files[] = $file->getFileName();
            }
        }
        return $files;
    }
```